# How to show lines connecting latitude and longitude points in world map?

Tags: python, r, google-maps, dictionary

I have get a CSV file of longitude and latitude like the following (the total length is 86 points in the CSV):

```
  Index       lon            lat
  1         2.352222    48.85661
  2         -72.922343  41.31632
  3         108.926694  34.25005
  4         -79.944163  40.44306
  5     -117.328119 33.97329
  6     -79.953423  40.4442
  7         -84.396285  33.77562
  8     -95.712891  37.09024
```

And now I want to plot a line from the point(32.06025,118.7969) to all these points(lon,lat) that like many arrow lines from one point.

I have try all this work in R and I have meet something strange.For example, if I use

```
  map('world2Hires')
  for (j in 1:length(location$lon)) {
  inter <- gcIntermediate(c(lon_nj, lat_nj), c(location$lon[j], location$lat[j]), n=100,         addStartEnd=TRUE)
  lines(inter, col="black", lwd=0.8)
  }
  View(location)
```

The result is like this:
[image: image of R]

If all the lines point to USA further come across the pacific ocean that the map is very good. But it doesn't.

Do you have any idea? How can I realize this? Any tools are OK although I have experience in Python and R.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to add argument `breakAtDateLine=TRUE` inside function `gcIntermediate()`. This will ensure that if the line cross the DateLine function will produce two segments and will not connect points with straight line. All results of this calculation I stored in list `gg`. This list contains data frame for each line or list of data frames of line consists of two segments.

```
library(mapdata)
library(geosphere)
lon_nj<-118.7969
lat_nj<-32.06025
location<-structure(list(Index = 1:8, lon = c(2.352222, -72.922343, 108.926694, 
-79.944163, -117.328119, -79.953423, -84.396285, -95.712891), 
    lat = c(48.85661, 41.31632, 34.25005, 40.44306, 33.97329, 
    40.4442, 33.77562, 37.09024)), .Names = c("Index", "lon", 
"lat"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

gg<-lapply(1:length(location$lon),function(j) {
  gcIntermediate(c(lon_nj, lat_nj), c(location$lon[j], 
                                      location$lat[j]), n=100,
                 breakAtDateLine=TRUE,
                 addStartEnd=TRUE)
})
```

This will change your list so that each segment is in separate data frame and not in list of list.

```
gg2<-unlist(lapply(gg, function(x) 
  if (class(x) == "list") x else list(x)), recursive=FALSE)
```

To plot those data again you can use function `lapply()`.

If you use `map("world)` then do just

```
map("world")
lapply(gg2,lines)
```

If you use `map('world2Hires')` then this map is based on 0-360 latitudes. So you have to add 360 to those `x` coordinate values that are negative.

```
map('world2Hires')
lapply(gg2,function(x) lines(ifelse(x[,1]>0,x[,1],x[,1]+360),x[,2]))
```

[image]